# How to combine storage from different linux servers across public network

Tags: linux, storage

I have dedicated hosting servers of 2 TB each, (7 of them) . Now i want to combine the unused space from them and converge them into other server . Note that the servers have public network .

Found solution such as ceph or xtreemfs but dont know if that actually provide what i need.

any hint ?

---

Actually the whole idea is to combine storage from multiple servers into one posix filesystem.

what above ISCSI over public net ?

Answer (score 2):

GlusterFS is also an option. It has a distributed type of translator than can combine storage from multiple servers into one posix filesystem.

Comment: This is the exact use case GlusterFS was created for - aggregating local server storage into a centralised filesystem

Answer (score 1):

If you got lanspeed access between them and your new server, you should be able to use any clusterfs. You could even use ATAoverEthernet, and then combine the devices with a raid filesystem of your choice.

If you have high latency between the hosts, things like sshfs, afs come to mind.

Please add more information of what you want to do with the storage and better info on the topology.

Comment: Thanks a lot, they are on same Datacentre so i think latency wont be an issue.  what about xtreemefs or ceph with posix compliant ?

Comment: Both of them seem posix compliant. I have not had active experiences with either of these.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to use this for, a cluster filesystem like GFS or OCFS2 might be needed.

Just for serving and organising the volumes to the servers, I'd suggest ISCSI and (Cluster-)LVM.

A similar setup with using the bare logical volumes as disks for VMs has worked out fine for me. Precautions against conflicts are taken via network.

Comment: Actually the whole idea is to combine storage from multiple servers into one posix filesystem.

what above ISCSI over public net ?